# SMTP python sends two emails when i run it once

Tags: python, email, smtp, jinja2, starttls

I have written a .py file to send a template email using jinja 2 and SMTP. The only issue I'm having is when I run the code once, the email sends twice (at the same time in the same email chain as an exact duplicate).

Here is the code I'm using:

```
from jinja2 import Environment, PackageLoader, select_autoescape

import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage
msg = EmailMessage()

content="hello"

def send_template_email(template, to, subj, **kwargs):
    env = Environment(
        loader=PackageLoader("send_template_email", "templates"),
        autoescape=select_autoescape(["html", "xml"])
    )
    template = env.get_template("email_template.html")
    send_email(to, subj, template.render(**kwargs))

def send_email(to, subj, body):
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
    server.starttls()
    server.login('sender_address@gmail.com','password')
    msg['Subject'] = subj
    msg['From'] = "sender_address@gmail.com"
    msg['To'] = to
    msg.set_content(body, subtype="html")
    server.send_message(msg)
    server.quit()

send_template_email(
    template="email_template.html",
    to="recipient@email.com",
    subj="TEST",
    content=content
)
```

in this example, recipient@email.com would receive 2 identical emails, but I only want them to receive one.

Comment: Can you please [edit] the question and make it a [mcve]? Is the template really needed? If so, is there something in the template that adds another recipient? (Can you include the template?)

Comment: In general: 1: the mail is really sent twice or 2: there are two addresses in one message or 3: some alias expansion at the recipient's site duplicates it. A carefull examination of the message headers should help to diagnose.